# Change the properties of a custom post type after it's been registered?

Tags: custom-post-types

The specific use case is that I have a CPT added through a plugin, and I'd like it to be hierarchical, but the post type options are hardcoded into the plugin.

Is it possible to change the properties of a custom post type after it's been added via `register_post_type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possible to manipulate CPT data after registration it's not very "clean" and harder for some things.

Specifically for hierarchical setting registration adds it to rewrite right away:

```
if ( $args->hierarchical )
    add_rewrite_tag( "%$post_type%", '(.+?)', $args->query_var ? "{$args->query_var}=" : "post_type=$post_type&pagename=" );
else
    add_rewrite_tag( "%$post_type%", '([^/]+)', $args->query_var ? "{$args->query_var}=" : "post_type=$post_type&name=" );
```

So you'll have to redo this really carefully and make sure it survives flushing rewrite rules properly.

Altogether it would be more robust to look into forking or extending that part of plugin in question and just register CPT like you need it to.

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah I was afraid of this.  Unfortunate to have to create a fork of the plugin to change one boolean, but you're probably correct that it's the cleaner option.